# Android: notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh my ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am getting a NullPointer exception when getting a method from a class to refresh my ListView. I am calling a method from a fragment inside an adapter's onclick event. Mostly every thing is working well, I just cant refresh the listview after entering new items/row in it.

```
public class Cashier extends Fragment {
    public SaleAdapter saleAdapter;
    List<SaleModel> saleModelList = new ArrayList<>()

    public view onCreateView(...) {
        load_sales();
    }

    public void load_sales() {
        saleModelList.clear();
        SQLiteHelper db = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor = db.showSales();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SaleModel saleModel = new SaleModel(            
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_PCODE)),
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_QUANTITY)),
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_SRP)),
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_TOTALPRICE))
                );
                saleModelList.add(saleModel);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    saleAdapter = new SaleAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_sale, saleModelList);
    lvSales.setAdapter(saleAdapter);
    saleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void refreshList() {
        saleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

From an Adapter I have to call the load_sales() method.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecycleView.Adapter .... {
    private List<ProductModel> productModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public ProductAdapter (Context context, List<ProductModel> productModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productModelList = productModelList;
    }

    class HolderData extends RecycleView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        view.OnClickListener(....) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = ....
            builder.setPositiveButton() {
                Cashier cashier = new Cashier();  //Declare cashier as new Cashier class
                cashier.refreshList();  //Uses the refreshList() to reload the ListView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxxx.fragment.Cashier.refershList(Cashier.java:112)
    at xxxx.utility.adapter.ProductAdapter$HolderData$1$1.onClick(ProductAdapter.java:121)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
```

Answer (score 0):

It throws null pointer because the SaleAdapter is not initialised.

When you call new Cashier() the cashier object will be initialised but other objects in Cashier class like the one SaleAdapter will initialize after load_sales() method is executed

So The biggest mistake is you should not do new Cashier() in your ProductAdapter. Pass the SaleAdapter fragment to ProductAdapter

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecycleView.Adapter .... {
    Cashier mCashier;
    public ProductAdapter(Cashier cashier){mCashier = cashier}
    ....
    class HolderData extends RecycleView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        view.OnClickListener(....) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = ....
            builder.setPositiveButton() {

                mCashier.refreshList();  //Uses the refreshList() to reload the ListView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and pass the cashier object from your fragment Cashier by calling 
    new ProductAdapter(this) from Cashier class

Comment: I am using my ProductAdapter in other instance, there will a 3rd parameter then...

Comment: public ProductAdapter (Context context, List<ProductModel> productModelList, Cashier cashier) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productModelList = productModelList;
        this.cashier = cashier;
    }

Comment: I am not doing new Cashier() in my SaleAdapter @_@

Comment: @Maki you are doing at ProductAdapter.

Comment: I still cant make it work =D any idea how to refresh the listview after i click on builder.setPositiveButton click event?

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize the adapter in the load_sales() methods,so first time you have to call load_sales method after that call refreshlist method

Comment: That is what happening right now... calling the refresh after the load

Answer (score 0):

> What you did wrong in the code is    **Cashier cashier = new
>   Cashier();** This line

when you use **new** Keyword means you create new object so here you created new object of Cashier  Fragment that didnt have view (view load when you commit transaction) when you call refresh method at that time your adapter is null

> What you have to do

**Prasanna Anbu** give perfect answer i am just add what hi forgot

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecycleView.Adapter .... {
    Cashier mCashier;
    ArrayList<ProductDetails> mProductList 
    public ProductAdapter(Cashier cashier,ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList ){
        mCashier = cashier;
        mProductList = productList ;
     } 
    ....
    class HolderData extends RecycleView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        view.OnClickListener(....) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = ....
            builder.setPositiveButton() {

               methodToAddDataInDatabase(); 
               cashier.load_sales();   // this method call when you want to load new instance of adapter
              //ArrayList<ProductDetails> myObject = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>(mProductList);
             // Refresh(myObject);
            }
        }
    }

public void Refresh(ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList) {
        mProductList .clear();
        mProductList .addAll(productList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is how to load adapter

```
ProductAdapter mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter (this, mProductList );
recyclerView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter );
```

Comment: I will pass Cashier as the context of the ProductAdapter? because right now im passing Context context... public ProductAdapter (Context context, List<ProductModel> productModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productModelList = productModelList;
    }

Comment: BTW, ProductAdapter = RecycleView while SaleAdapter = ListView

Comment: I would like to show all the codes buy stackoferflow wount allow me =(

Comment: when you want to pass context from fragment use getActivity() and pass current fragment use this keyword

Comment: Here's my look like... I have a fragment that has a (1) RecyclerView that holds the PRODUCTS, I am using a ProductModel and ProductAdapter for this. (2) ListView that holds the SALES, I am using a SaleModel and SaleAdapter for this. In my fragment, the user will choose a PRODUCT from the <1>RecyclerView and opens an AlertDialog.Builder that allows the user to enter a number and saves it all to a SQLite Database. Everything from here is working well, data is being saved in the database. By using the <2>SaleModel and SaleAdapter, I can view the list of sales in my ListView, <to be continued...>

Comment: I can view the list of sales in my ListView only if I reload the apps. Or open a different fragment and go back to this fragment. Now, my problem is that how can I refresh the ListView or the SaleAdapter after clicking setPositiveBotton() in my AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: Try with ----  methodToAddDataInDatabase();  cashier.load_sales(); this method in adapter click   it should work 100 %  (edited answer)